How to deal su dynamic components imported into unity don't work?
Su dynamic components imported into unity after clicking can not achieve dynamic effects .I set the dynamic component properties for my door to rotate in su, and in su I can click successfully to implement the function, but when introduced to unity, it does not work.
Should I do it in su or Unity? How to operate?
